# What happens when one assigns a string value to an integer variable in c++?

Tags: c++, variables

I just started learning c++ (so forgive me for my noobish query). Here's some code I wrote as an exercise:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int foo;
    cin >> foo;

    int bar;

    cin >> bar;
    cout << "foo plus bar is " << foo+bar<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now this code works perfectly fine when both the inputs are numbers. But when I enter a string for the first input (just to see what happens) the program does not ask me for the second input and `cout`s the result as `foo plus bar is 0`. What I'd like to know is why is the program skipping my second `cin` when I assign a string to an integer variable. Thanking you for your help.

Comment: Your `cin` will never be "ignored". In situations like this you should direct your thinking to "what _is_ my `cin` doing, then? and why?" and to find out you read the documentation. Carefully.

Comment: Where's the c++ standard documentation hosted? All I have at the moment is Bjarne Stroustrup's 'The C++ Programming language'. Is that what you mean by documentation?

Comment: For example http://cppreference.com

Comment: @Bolt64: There's nothing centralised for C++. That book is a good start, but for a _reference_ you want http://cppreference.com, backed by the standard.

Comment: But the standard is licensed by ISO. If you don't want to spend money, read the standard *proposals*, which are free; but I can't remember where you can download them...

Comment: @leemes: You're referring to the _drafts_, and http://www.isocpp.org is a good source.

Comment: Ah right, now I remember. Thank you, I confused the wording. Proposals are proposed changes only, one document for each topic / feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A stream has a internal state. If an input fails the state is set to indicate the error and all further inputs will fail, unless that state is cleared.

In your case you should initialize foo and bar with zero.

Test the stream state:

```
if( ! (cin >> foo)) {
    // Error
}
```

Same with bar

If you have resolved the input failure you can use `cin.clear()` to clear the error state.

Comment: So even if I try to assign a string to foo and bar, `cin` will fail the test and foo and bar will remain 0?

Comment: @Bolt64 The string is still waiting to get extracted. The error state will not go away automatically.